# Is that make sense to construct a learning Model using only one feature?

Tags: machine-learning, genetic-programming, adaboost, supervised-learning

in order to improve the accuracy of an adaboost classifier (for image classification), I am using genetic programming to derive new statistical Measures. Every Time when a new feature is generated, i evaluate its fitness by training an adaboost Classifier and by testing its performances. But i want to know if that procedure is correct; I mean the use of a single feature to train a learning model.

Comment: This is a binary classifier (feature is there, feature is not there) which is a valid approach. SVMs for example only do binary classifiction. But I don't know much about ADA Boost and how good this one fits for that task

Comment: i am using a multiclass version of adaboost (AdaboostM2) but the problem is not there; i am testing the discriminative power of the generated features separately (one classifier for each feature). Is this 'normal' to build a prediction model based only on one feature?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can build a model on one feature. I assume, that by "one feature" you mean simply one number in `R` (otherwise, it would be completely "traditional" usage). However this means, that you are building a classifier in one-dimensional space, and as such - many classifiers will be redundant (as it is really a simple problem). What is more important - checking whether you can correctly classify objects using one particular dimensions **does not mean** that it is a good/bad feature once you use combination of them. In particular it may be the case that:

- Many features may "discover" the same phenomena in data, and so - each of them separatly can yield good results, but once combined - they won't be any better then each of them (as they simply capture **same information**)
- Features may be useless until used in combination. Some phenomena can be described only in multi-dimensional space, and if you are analyzing only one-dimensional data - you won't ever discover their true value, as a simple example consider four points `(0,0),(0,1),(1,0),(1,1)` such that `(0,0),(1,1)` are elements of one class, and rest of another. If you look separatly on each dimension - then the best possible accuracy is `0.5` (as you always have points of two different classes in exactly same points - 0 and 1). Once combined - you can easily separate them, as it is a `xor` problem.

To sum up - it is ok to build a classifier in one dimensional space, but:

- Such problem can be solved without "heavy machinery".
- Results **should not** be used as a base of feature selection (or to be more strict - this can be very deceptive).